# What ModuleVersion store in Doors dxl?

Tags: module, baseline, ibm-doors

I often faced the type **ModuleVersion** but I can not understand what a variable from this type contains? I read that:

```
The "Module" DXL Type represents a loaded **ModuleVersion** (current or Baseline).
```

So we have a specification and it has different versions in time:
for example from Monday for our Module we will have Baseline 1.1
- then we add new requirements and after one month we create Baseline 1.2
- and so on...
We have 1.0 ,1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 2, 2.1<-current
And when we want to load a module form a specific baseline, we use this **ModuleVersion** or..? I do not understand. Can you give some example with proper explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You are right. The handle `ModuleVersion` represents a saved state of a module. Several functions accept such a handle, e.g.

```
 Module load(ModuleVersion modver, bool display)
 Baseline baseline(ModuleVersion modver)
```

which are used to load such a saved state / access a baseline -- depending on which result type you need for your task. You may retrieve such a `ModuleVersion` handle using the `moduleVersion` function.

Giving an example would make more sense if we knew what you are trying to achieve. The DXL Reference Manual already contains a few examples: check the description of `baselineSet`, `for {string|ModuleVersion} in recentModules`
or `for AttrType in ModuleProperties`.

Comment: I do not understand what we gain with this ModuleVersion, we specify the specific version of the Module, but does it open the module when we work on ModuleVersion level and what kind of operations can do on ModuleVersion ?

Comment: I understand it to be just a handle. You get it by explicitly retrieving and can use it to load a module or baseline.